# Heroku CLI error

Tags: heroku

Unable to use Heroku CLI anymore:

Error

```
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Setting up node-v4.1.1... !    rename C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\download200968087\file C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
error loading plugin commands
error loading plugin topics
error loading plugin commands
```

I reinstalled git then heroku toolbelt.

Ran git bash as admin.

Im on windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the executable under `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe` and you should be able to proceed.

This is a permission error. The environment under which the script runs doesn't have permission to delete that file. You, however, likely do.

Comment: It's a permission error. The environment under which the script runs doesn't have permission to delete that file.