# Deploying node js server on heroku not getting past heroku login step

Tags: node.js, windows, heroku

I have a server ready which i host locally from my laptop. I wanted to host this server on heroku. After installing heroku toolbelt i tried accessing the heroku command from the command prompt. After installing toolbelt and nodejsv-4.1.2 it starts installing node js again and then just doesnt go any further.

```
    Setting up node-v4.1.2... !    rename C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\do
wnload450328587\file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.2-windows-x86
\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
```

I am not able to bypass this, I am absolutely a beginner with heroku so any guidance is appreciated. I did goto the heroku dev site, but since im not ble to get past the first step i cannot even proceed to do the rest. Please help.

Exact problem from heroku login

```
C:\Users\user>heroku login
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Setting up node-v4.1.2... done
Setting up node-v4.1.2... !    rename C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\do
wnload150192496\file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.2-windows-x86
\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Heroku CLI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853495/heroku-cli-error)
I had the same issue -> deleted the executable under C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\heroku\node-v4.1.2-windows-x86\bin\node.exe.  Then with an administrative command prompt ran 'heroku --version'.  This re-installed heroku with the right level of privileges.

Comment: hey @wanton, I see and am sorry for reposting a previously asked question. I just couldnt find it. Anyways both solutions work absolutely fine, including yours of course. Thank you for the prompt response, saved me a lot of self exploration. YOU DA MAN! thanks again, and I'll make sure I see stack properly before posting further questions